# Count up numbers in a specific time period, Java, Android

Tags: java, android, count, textview

How do I make a count up in TextView from `0` to a `number` in 5 seconds?

The `number` variable will always have different value, thats why I need it to always count up from `0` to `number` in 5 seconds.

If i do a `while` and the `number` = 1982654324441 it will take to long to count it up.

This is how I do it now:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (counter < number) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(0,01);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText("" + counter);
                }
            });
            counter++;
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: what is `Thread.sleep(0,01);` supposed to do? Use `Thread.sleep(1000);` to wait one second and change your `number` to 5.

Comment: I cant wait 1 second each time I will add the new number to the textView. If number = 500 it will take 500 seconds to count from 0 to 500... This is to make a nice animation of the count up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method: It should work for all numbers > 0 and you can also adjust the update interval.

```
final int TIME_TO_COUNT = 5000; //ms
//Update interval in ms. Consider that the screen cannot be updated as often as you want.
//17ms (about 60FPS) sound reasonable
final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 17;
final int number = 5001; //Can be any number between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE;

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        double counter = 0.0;
        while (counter < number) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(Math.ceil(counter)));
                }
            });
            counter += (number / (double) TIME_TO_COUNT) * UPDATE_INTERVAL;
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Perfect! Works really nice. I have to modify it a little since I will handle very big numbers! Super thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:
(works for a number less than 5000 with minor rounding errors)

```
int stepTime = 5000/totalCount;
final CountDownTimer dialogTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, stepTime) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              int num = (5000-millisUntilFinished) *stepTime;
              // use this num to set text
        }

        public void onFinish() {
        }
    };
```

Edit:

Try this maybe:
(Warning: untested code)

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeInMillis();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    counter= number * (System.currentTimeInMillis() - startTime) /5000.0
    while (counter < number) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(0,01);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        textView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textView.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}).start();

Comment: This code looks like it will only work for numbers < 5000. And even there I guess it will not be really reliable: You will have rounding errors in stepTime and num.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does the counting up, but does not use any Android functionality. So you need to modify it a bit to fit your needs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    countUpTo(5, 5);
    countUpTo(2, 7000);
}

private static void countUpTo(final int seconds, final int number) throws InterruptedException {
    int updateInterval = 100;
    int numUpdates = seconds * 1000 / updateInterval;
    double updateBy = number / (double) numUpdates;

    double count = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < seconds*1000L) {
        long updateStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((int) count);
        count += updateBy;
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - updateStartTime;
        Thread.sleep(updateInterval-elapsedTime);
    }
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

The important aspects here are:

- Define an update interfal (in my code every 100 ms)
- Count in `double` so everything also works with small numbers (avoid rounding errors)
- Define the update steps (how far you need to proceed with every update)
- Sleep for updateInterval - the time it took to update the UI.